# Nomachine only shows a black screen

Tags: nomachine

I an trying to connect to a node on my server and when I login through no-machine, only a black screen shows. How can I troubleshoot this?

I'm using the Mac client to connect to a linux server. Installed the latest versions on both.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this to me:

https://www.nomachine.com/TR04L04396

NoMachine are already aware of it from a report in their forums

https://www.nomachine.com/forums/topic/screen-goes-black#post-4060